# Elementary: Confusion with usage of plural form in present simple

Tags: present-tense

Have been following a book, but I am getting confused.

See the below 2 sentences:

1) In Britain the banks usually open at 9:30 in the morning.

2) The City Museum closes at 5 o'clock in the evening.

Here question is why 'open' is in singular form in first sentence while 'closes' is in plural form in second?

The book states the following rule for pluralization:

I/we/you/they -> singular
He/she/it -> plural

In my understanding both 'The Britain banks' and 'City Museum' falls in second category (It)

Please help
Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us what research you've done so far regarding your question?

Comment: You've followed a wrong book! Both sentences are grammatically correct.

Comment: Oh is it, it is one of the exercises in Essential English Grammar by Raymond Murphy... With answer keys, I have tried gathering the explanation else where too, but none explains to my satisfaction

Comment: I wonder if you are getting confused by the "s" which turns nouns in to plurals, but does the "opposite" for verbs. Singular noun ->boy; plural noun ->boy**s**. But for verbs, if the subject is **singular** we put an "s" on the verb, but for a plural subject, we do not put an "s". So the verb and the subject frequently have opposite "s"-behavior. Example: "The boy see**s**.", but "The boy**s** see."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"In Britain, the ***banks***" is plural. It's talking about ***all of the banks*** in Britain. The pronoun for that would be *they*, which would fall into the first category: third person plural.

The second sentence however, is talking about one particular museum, The City Museum, AKA *it*, so that falls into the second category.

Nonetheless, neither of those verbs are "*plural*". Pluralization is for nouns, rather than verbs. The verb is only conjugated to match the person and that *s* in "*closes*" is called *the third person s*, not a plural form of the verb.

You could read more about this Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary note about [third person singular](http://learnersdictionary.com/qa/third-person-singular-s-simple-present-tense).

Comment: In Britain, banks....same result though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's the explanation I was looking for, you are right about plurazition of nouns.. my bad.

Comment: What do you mean Lambie?